# Tabbar as main view (left side) of splitview controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uitabbar

Just like the Dropbox app for iPad I want to add Tabbar in the main view controller of splitview.. wondering what is the best way to achieve this?

Checkout the screen grab of ipad dropbox app... I am referring to the tabbar used on bottom left.

[image: image of dropbox iPad app. I am referring to the tabbar at bottom left of the screen]

Comment: sorry i m not getting describe little more

Comment: within ipad in main view controller (left side) of splitview I want to use the tabbar controller instead of navbar controller.

Comment: your question is not clear yet for getting right answer .

Comment: hav added more details with image.. i hope it will make question clear.

Comment: hmm .. i have seen this first time sorry yogesh.i cant help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the Navigation Controller of your Split View Controller in Xcode and in the properties panel it will give you checkboxes to enable/disable top navigation bar and bottom toolbar for it (Dropbox app in your screenshot have both, so you should check both of them if you need the same layout).

Comment: it means that I hav to add buttons in this toolbar and make it work like a tabbar?

Comment: You will need to add things called UITabBarItem to that toolbar, they will handle the tab switching for you